# Adding underline to current page section in single page react app with Chakra.ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, header, single-page-application, chakra-ui

I am building a single page react website using Chakra.ui component library. However, I do have different page sections that you can jump to from the header. I need it so that when you are on a certain page section, that section is underlined in the header. I've tried many different approaches, but none of them seem to work.

Code for my Header section:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link, animateScroll as scroll } from "react-scroll";
import { Box, Flex, Text, Button } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import Logo from "../ui/Logo";
import { LinkBox, LinkOverlay } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";


const MenuItem = ({ children, isLast, to = "/", ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <LinkBox
      width="auto"
      height="75px"
      marginTop={["auto", "auto", "auto", "25px"]}
      marginRight="10px"

      borderBottom={
        (window.location.href.split("#")[1] || "") == to
          ? "3px solid #333"
          : "transparent"
      }
      borderColor={
        (window.location.href.split("#")[1] || "") == to
          ? "primary.100"
          : "none"
      }

      _hover={{
        borderBottom: "3px solid #333",
        borderBottomColor: "primary.100",
      }}
    >
      <LinkOverlay href={to}>
        <Box
          width="auto"
          height={to == "#/donate" ? "auto" : "50px"}
          marginRight="10px"
          marginLeft="10px"
 
          borderRadius={to == "#/donate" ? "50px" : "none"}
          bg={to == "#/donate" ? "primary.100" : "none"}
          padding={to == "#/donate" ? "10px" : "none"}

        >
          <Text

            marginRight="5px"
            marginLeft="5px"
            display="block"
            fontSize="2xl"
            fontWeight
            lineHeight={to == "#/donate" ? "auto" : "55px"}
            align="center"
            textColor={to == "#/donate" ? "primary.200" : "primary.100"}
            {...rest}
          >
            {children}
          </Text>
        </Box>
      </LinkOverlay>
    </LinkBox>
  );
};

const CloseIcon = () => (
  <svg width="24" viewBox="0 0 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <title>Close</title>
    <path
      fill="white"
      d="M9.00023 7.58599L13.9502 2.63599L15.3642 4.04999L10.4142 8.99999L15.3642 13.95L13.9502 15.364L9.00023 10.414L4.05023 15.364L2.63623 13.95L7.58623 8.99999L2.63623 4.04999L4.05023 2.63599L9.00023 7.58599Z"
    />
  </svg>
);

const MenuIcon = () => (
  <svg
    width="24px"
    viewBox="0 0 20 20"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    fill="white"
  >
    <title>Menu</title>
    <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z" />
  </svg>
);

const Header = (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleMenu = () => setShow(!show);

  return (
    <Flex
      as="nav"
      align="center"
      justify="space-between"
      height={show ? "none" : "100px"}
      wrap="wrap"
      w="100%"
      p={3}
      bg={["primary.200", "primary.200", "primary.200", "primary.200"]}
      color={["white", "white", "white", "white"]}
      {...props}
    >
      <Flex align="center">
        <Logo
          w="85px"
          color={["white", "white", "primary.500", "primary.500"]}
        />

        <Text

          marginLeft="20px"
          display="block"
          fontSize="2xl"
          fontWeight
          lineHeight="55px"
          align="center"
          textColor="primary.100"
        >
          YBDC
        </Text>
      </Flex>

      <Box display={{ base: "block", md: "none" }} onClick={toggleMenu}>
        {show ? <CloseIcon /> : <MenuIcon />}
      </Box>

      <Box
        display={{ base: show ? "block" : "none", md: "block" }}
        flexBasis={{ base: "100%", md: "auto" }}
      >
        <Flex
          align="center"
          justify={["center", "space-between", "flex-end", "flex-end"]}
          direction={["column", "row", "row", "row"]}
          pt={[4, 4, 0, 0]}
          ml="10"
          mr="10"
        >
          <MenuItem to="/">HOME</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem to="#/about">ABOUT </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem to="#/impact">IMPACT </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem to="#/volunteer">VOLUNTEER</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem to="#/donate" isLast>
            DONATE
          </MenuItem>
        </Flex>
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Chakra UI has no built-in functionality of current/active links. This leaves us with two options: implementing custom logic and using other libraries.

The easiest of two will be to use react-scroll library that already has this functionality.

```
import { Link as ScrollLink } from 'react-scroll';
```

And then use it wherever you want like so:

```
<ScrollLink
    to='home'
    activeClass="active"
    spy={true}
    smooth={true}
    offset={0}
    duration={1500}>
Home
</ScrollLink >
```

`to` prop is referencing to ID of the element you want to scroll to, so in my example it will be an element with ID `#home`. Make sure to pass `spy={true}` prop and `activeClass="yourclassname"`. You can later use this className to style active links of the header. `offset` prop defines how close or far from element the class will be toggled.    And lastly, `duration` prop defines how long the scroll animation will continue for.

Comment: Ah I see. Where and how would I use the className "active" to do the styling? Do I have to make a CSS file for that? Or is there a way I can do it in my code? Also, in your example, does ScrollLink have to encapsulate the entire section? Or is this just the link to the section?

Comment: If you have global CSS styles somewhere in your code I would implement the 'active' class there. For that you would also add a custom class to the ScrollLink. So let's say my ScrollLink has a className of 'myLink', that means whenever this link is active I can reference to it inside CSS as `.myLink.active`. So you can do something like `.myLink.active { color: 'blue' }` inside your CSS. I tried implementing the same logic inside the `sx` prop of Chakra-UI but couldn't get it working properly. So CSS is the only way to go.

Comment: Although you can encapsulate whole elements inside the ScrollLink, there is no need to do that. ScrollLink represents the `a` tag so the InnerHTML of ScrollLink is the text that is going to be shown